# Entity Framework DbSet.Add(entity) generating the same insert statement although I provide different values in the second try

Tags: entity-framework

I am testing my repository class with the following scenario:

**First**, I issue a call to

```
Insert(TEntity entity)
```

with an already existing entity. It works good, EF gives me a duplicate key error, which is fine.

**After that**, I reissue a call to

```
Insert(TEntity entity)
```

but now with different data; but the EF generates the same SQL statement as in the previous call.

```
public class EfRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : Entity
{
    protected EcmsDbContext Context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> DbSet;


    public EfRepository(EcmsDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DbSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual async Task<bool> Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            DbSet.Add(entity);
            return await Context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  We don't know what your calls to `Insert()` look like so we cannot duplicate your issue.

Comment: If you test two different things (duplicate insert, nonduplicate insert), then why is there a **First** and **After**? Shouldn't the two tests work independent from one another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to do an insert, then as an exception handler, attempting to issue an insert with a new, adjusted entity, if you haven't disposed of the DbContext, or detached the originally added entity, the same "first" entity will still be trying to save.

I believe this should work:

```
try
{
    DbSet.Add(entity);
    return await Context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    return false;
}
```